# C# Ambiguous reference between self built Node<T> \ List<T> Class to system's Node and List

Tags: c#, list, oop, compiler-errors, nodes

I have built my own Node\List Classes in c#,  and I have tried to use them in a new project, but vs seems to give me countless errors which I can't figure out how to solve out.

Code :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Students;
using Nodes;






namespace schoolNodes
{
    class Program
    {

        public static Student Best(List<Student> x)
        {
            Node<Student> p = x.GetFirst();
            Student tal, talmax = null;
            float mem, max = 0;

            while (p != null)
            {
                tal = p.GetValue();
                mem = tal.Avg();
                if (mem > max)
                {
                    max = mem; 
                    talmax = tal; 
                }
                p = p.GetNext();
            }
            return talmax;
        }

        public static int NumTeacherOfClass(string s, List<Teacher> l)
        {
            Node<Teacher> p = l.GetFirst();
            int n = 0;

            while (p != null)
            {
                if (p.GetValue().CheckClass(s))
                    n++;
                p = p.GetNext();
            }

            return n;
        }
```

Wherever there is List<...> it gives me an error.
The names space where I put my Node\List classes in is called "Nodes".

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `System.Collections.Generic` together with your `Nodes`, which contains `List` definition. This leads to compiler error. Try to using full name with namespace, like `Nodes.List<Student>` instead of `List<Student>`.

Comment: I tried `using Nodes.List;
using Nodes.Node;`     But it gives me and error where it asks for a Value for List<T> and Node<T>    So I tried `using Nodes.List<T>;
using Nodes.Node<T>;` but then it errors me that there is a `;` missing before the `<T>` .

Comment: Maybe you dont understand me correctly, I mean instead of "List<Student> x" write "Nodes.List<Student> x". Also please update your answer with error message and information about Nodes classes. You can drop implementation details, just definition.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working perfectly!  
Any suggestions how can I avoid this situation next time?

Comment: In such case you can name your classes differently or always use your class with full name. But this problem causes only with generics type because in other cases you can "using" required class like `using Node = MyNodes.Node`